# How can I get the Xcode debugger to step into the assembly of a function?

Tags: xcode, debugging, assembly

Whenever I try to step into a function for which I don't have the source code, e.g. anything in an Apple library, the debugger just skips to the next line. How can I have it go into the assembly instead? I can workaround this by setting a symbolic breakpoint for the function that I want to step into, but this is less convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold Control when pressing the step controls. Works for me in Xcode 12.

> The stepping controls have alternative operations for working with disassembly or threads. You use the Control and Control-Shift modifier keys to call these alternatives. Press Control to step by assembly language instruction instead of by statement (the step icons change to show a dot rather than a line under the arrow) or Control-Shift to step into or over the active thread only while holding other threads stopped (the step icons show a dashed rather than solid line below the arrow).

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html